# Should I const_cast "this" when a method only accepts Foo *const?

Tags: c++, qt

I have a class `Foo` which is in a self referencing tree-like structure (minimally):

```
class Foo {
    public:
        // Gets this child's position relative to it's parent.
        int getPosition() const {
             return parent->indexOf(this);
        }

        int indexOf(const Foo *const child) const {
            return children.indexOf(child); // this line causes an error.
        }
    private:
        Foo *parent;
        QList<Foo *> children;
}
```

The line `return children.indexOf(child)` expects `const T &value` to be passed as per the [QList docs](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qlist.html#indexOf), this resolves to `Foo *const &value` for my scenario.

In order for my `getPosition()` method to call my own `indexOf()` method it is required to have a signature of `const Foo *child` at minimum in order to pass `this` from a const method. (Since this is `const Foo *const`).

My code will not compile however as `const Foo *const child` cannot be cast to `Foo *const child` for `QList::indexOf`. Neither of my methods modify the object state so they should be const (i.e. I don't want to un-cost `getPosition` to receive a non-const `this`).

So the question is, how do I go from `this` in a const context (`const Foo *const`) to what `QList::indexOf` requires. Should I be const casting `this` inside `getPosition` since I know that my `indexOf` (and subsequent calls) will not mutate it?

Is there something else I should have done? Perhaps my design is faulty.

Comment: Is the real issue here that `QList::indexOf` isn't a `const` method, and it should be?

Comment: I don't think there's anything you could have done better. If anything, `QList`'s design might be improved, to allow as search argument anything which can be equality-compared to its element type. Then searching for `Foo const*` would be no problem. But I assume that you are not the designer of `QList`.

Comment: @Dave `QList::indexOf` is a const method. http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qlist.html#indexOf

Comment: @Dave QList is in fact const (see the link of OP) and for QLists with value types there is no problem since the argument is `const T&`. In this case the const correctness is broken by the fact that `const (Foo *)&` is a const pointer to non-const Foo which will not work from a const function in Foo since Foo is const there.

Comment: @celtschk - From the documentation, `QList` appears to be designed as you describe, you can search for a `Foo const*` with no problem.

Comment: @CoryKlein: From the documentation you linked to, it is *not* designed as I describe. It takes a `T const&` which for `T=Foo*` is a `Foo* const&`. You cannot bind a `Foo const* const` to a `Foo* const&` (nor should you be able to, because it would violate const correctness).

Comment: @CoryKlein The signature of QList::indexOf for `Foo*` is: `int QList<Foo*>::indexOf(Foo * const & value, int from = 0) const` which does not allow the argument to be `Foo const *`. [as celtschk already stated...]

Comment: Ah, I concede my point - I didn't complete the full substitution for `T=Foo*`.

Comment: Any time I see a container with a raw pointer value type, red lights start flashing in my mind.  QList already stores its entries as an array of pointers internally, so you've really got an array of Foo** here.  This looks like some kind of intrusive tree structure, in which case each node should probably control the lifecycle of its children.  Perhaps something like QList<Foo> would be more appropriate.

Comment: I am controlling the lifecycle of the children inside the nodes using Qt's parent object system. In Qt a QObject can be assigned to another QObject as parent. When a parent is destroyed it also destroys sub objects. Can I confirm I'm not mis-using QList though - When something is passed to `QList::append` I think it copies it using `new` and then internally it is that new pointer that it stores. So when you need *the* object you pass you have to use `QList<Foo *>` surely? I'll see if I can get away with values and copy constructors in this instance though. Am I understanding this correctly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is a perfectly reasonable use case for `const_cast`, however it's not `this` you need to `const_cast`, but `child`. In this case, `QList::indexOf` expects a constant pointer to a `Foo` (`Foo* const`) but `child` is a constant pointer to a constant `Foo` (`const Foo* const`). There is no implicit conversion from `Foo* const` to `const Foo* const` because that would remove the const-ness from the value being pointed to.

So, to fix your code I would change the line to

```
return children.indexOf(const_cast<Foo*>(child));
```

You know `QList::indexOf` is not going to modify whatever `child` points to, so this won't produce undefined behavior. I would however add a comment explaining why the `const_cast` is necessary.